# Unable to pass Automator Finder input as output in AppleScript

Tags: input, applescript, automator, finder

**Overall goal**: Ideally I want to go through the file list received from *Find Finder Items* and pass each file to a script/automator block.

**Right now**: I'm trying to loop through each file that gets passed from the *Find Finder Items* block in Automator and make sure I'm able to correctly pass it as an output again. However, as soon as I "touch" any item from *input* I'm unable to pass it out correctly. See the attached screenshot.

[image: Automator project screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
set end of file_list to contents of f
```

The reason is `f` represents a **reference** to the object (e.g. `item 1 of input`) not the object itself.
`contents of` dereferences the object.